# Two Ambiguous types in the swift header file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, header-files

When I try to execute my partly Swift app on the Xcode simulator, two of my types are reported as ambiguous. Same thing happens when I try to archive it, but both my iOS 7 iPhone and iOS 8.1 iPad report no problem. That would be fine if only archiving were not needed to submit the update to the App Store. Those are the errors:

> iPuja Pro.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPuja.build/DerivedSources/iPuja-Swift.h:80:67:
>   Reference to 'EKSourceType' is ambiguous
>   iPuja_ProAppDelegate.m:13:9: In file included from /Users/fbartolom/Documents/cocoa applications/iPuja Pro/Classes/iPuja_ProAppDelegate.m:13:
>   iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/Headers/EKTypes.h:131:3:
>   Candidate found by name lookup is 'EKSourceType'
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/Headers/EKTypes.h:131:3:
>   Candidate found by name lookup is 'EKSourceType'
>   /Users/fbartolom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPuja_Pro-geuzolcwoljzlocablkrjyizzrbj/Build/Intermediates/iPuja
>   Pro.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPuja.build/DerivedSources/iPuja-Swift.h:82:59:
>   Reference to 'EKCalendarType' is ambiguous
>   iPuja Pro/Classes/iPuja_ProAppDelegate.m:13:9: In file included from
>   iPuja
>   Pro/Classes/iPuja_ProAppDelegate.m:13:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/Headers/EKTypes.h:111:3:
>   Candidate found by name lookup is 'EKCalendarType'
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/Headers/EKTypes.h:111:3:
>   Candidate found by name lookup is 'EKCalendarType'

What could be the problem and how to fix it? That is my first piece of Swift programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the including of the EventKit library in the app delegate header file. Of course I did not get the connection, but getting rid of all references to EventKit in the Objective-c part fixed the issue.